# Appending text to etree element for html markdown

Tags: python, html, markdown

I'm using python markdown to do the following:

When there is an expression of the form `[test]`, I want to render it as

```
<span>[<a>test</a>]</span>
```

To that end, I'm applying an extension to markdown's inlinePatterns:

```
PATTERN = r'\[(test)\]'

class PerceptionPattern(Pattern):
    def handleMatch(self, m):
        span = etree.Element('span')
        anchor = etree.SubElement(span, "a")
        span.text = markdown.util.AtomicString("[")
        span.tail = markdown.util.AtomicString("]")

        anchor.text = m.group(2)
        return span

class TestExtension(markdown.extensions.Extension):
    """Adds cite extension to Markdown class"""

    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        """Modifies inline patterns"""
        md.inlinePatterns.add('test', PerceptionPattern(PATTERN), '<not_strong')
```

However, this is returning

```
<span>[]<a>test</a></span>
```

I'm not sure `.tail` is the correct attribute, but I'm not finding the correct syntax.

How can I do this?

---

Full program

```
from markdown.inlinepatterns import Pattern
from markdown.util import etree
from markdown import Markdown
import markdown

PATTERN = r'\[(test)\]'


class TestPattern(Pattern):
    def handleMatch(self, m):
        span = etree.Element('span')
        anchor = etree.SubElement(span, "a")
        span.text = markdown.util.AtomicString("[")
        span.tail = markdown.util.AtomicString("]")
        #anchor.tail = markdown.util.AtomicString("]")

        anchor.text = m.group(2)
        return span


class TestExtension(markdown.extensions.Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        """Modifies inline patterns"""
        md.inlinePatterns.add('test_pattern', TestPattern(PATTERN), '<not_strong')

md = Markdown(extensions=[TestExtension()])

print md.convert(u'[test]')
```

Comment: Can you include a complete program that demonstrates the problem? See http://SSCCE.ORG/.

Comment: @Robᵩ , added full example, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that implementing the syntax `[test]` is not the best choice as it is already in [use](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%5Btest%5D%0A%0A%5Btest%5D%3A+http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com) as an undocumented feature of most implementations (including python's, which you are trying to alter/extend).

Additionally, the output you're trying to achieve is already possible with straight markdown (minus the otherwise useless span). Just do: `\[[test]()\]`. That is: escape the literal brackets and insert a markdown link between them (with a blank url if that's what you want). See the [output](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%5C%5B%5Btest%5D%28%29%5C%5D) on Babelmark.

Of course, I realize your example may just be a simplified implementation of something a little more complex that is part of a larger system and requires a simple syntax that can be used by non-expert markdown authors. So to answer the actual question you asked:

I'm assuming the span is to allow you to insert the brackets as text (clever by the way). However, the closing bracket would be the tail of the anchor, not the span. You want it to come after the closing anchor tag, but not after the closing span tag.

```
>>> from markdown.util import etree
>>> span = etree.Element('span')
>>> anchor = etree.SubElement(span, 'a')
>>> span.text = '['
>>> anchor.tail = ']'
>>> anchor.text = 'test'
>>> etree.tostring(span)
'<span>[<a>test</a>]</span>'
```

Your code should be outputting this :`<span>[<a>test</a></span>]`. Notice the closing bracket is the tail on the span here rather than the tail on the anchor.

Of course, it appears that you are getting neither of the above as output. It would seem that markdown is messing things up somehow. Wrapping the brackets in `AtomicString()` is the right move to avoid them getting mistaken for other syntax<del>, but I'm not sure how the span's tail is being appended to the text in your example.</del>

<del>Have you tried inserting your inlinePattern earlier? Perhaps before any bracket related patterns? Say before the 'reference' pattern (`'<reference'`). See if that helps.</del>

**Edit:** It turns out that there is a recently discovered bug in Python-Markdown which does weird things when an inlinePattern returns a complex Element; specifically, an element with children, especially when tails are involved. You can find more info in this [comment](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/253#issuecomment-33914414) in the related bug report. When that issue is resolved, then your code will work with the one tweak to which element's tail you put the closing bracket in (as I explained above). Until that bug is fixed, I'm afraid this won't work. You'll have to resort to the solutions which don't require an extension (escaping the brackets) for the time being.